# Spring security manually authentication not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

i'm changing an existing app with spring boot, this app not use spring security for authentication, the authentication is a method in a controller, so i want use spring security and i'm trying to use manually authentication in spring security but not working, below you can see the code:

Controller:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<UsuarioRequest> login(@RequestBody UsuarioRequest request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
        throws AppException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsulog(), request.getUsupass());
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(authToken);
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    UsuarioRequest usuario = usuarioFacadeAPI.findByUsername(request.getUsulog());
    return new ResponseEntity<UsuarioRequest>(usuario, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private SiscoAuthenticationProvider siscoAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(SiscoAuthenticationProvider siscoAuthenticationProvider) {
    super();
    this.siscoAuthenticationProvider = siscoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(siscoAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authenticationProvider(siscoAuthenticationProvider).authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/login/api/**", "/zona/api/**", "/rol/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}


@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

}
```

CustomAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class SiscoAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

private static final String ROLE = "ROLE_";
@Autowired
private UsuarioServiceAPI usuarioServiceAPI;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = null;
    try {
        UsuarioRequest request = usuarioServiceAPI.authenticate(authentication.getPrincipal().toString(), authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        List<RolRequest> rols = request.getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RolRequest rol : rols) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE+rol.getRolnom()));
        }
        token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials(), authorities);
    } catch (AppException e) {
        String message = BundleLoader.getMessage(e.getDetails().getBundle(), e.getDetails().getKey(),
                LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message, e);
    }
    return token;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
}

}
```

For the permitAll config no problem occurred, but any other request returns 403 error code even after authentication is success, i suspect that in the controller the SecurityContextHolder not update the authentication, by this the user is always anonymous.

Comment: is `token` being created properly in `authenticate` method?

Comment: How will the user authenticate if to get to the /authenticate endpoint you must be authenticated?

Comment: Hi Andronicus, yes the `token` it's created properly in `authenticate` method the SecurityContext is updated successfully, but when i try access to other methods spring return a 403 error.

Comment: Hi NatFar, in the `SecurityConfig` class i was created a `antMatcher` with permitAll for the URL `"/login/api/**"`, the method authenticate is part of a controller with that URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for the problem, i changed the Spring Security Config class, specifically the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` code below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();

   http.authenticationProvider(siscoAuthenticationProvider).authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/login/api/**", "/zona/api/**", "/rol/api/**").not().authenticated()
            .anyRequest().not().anonymous();
}
```

the prev config was have problems, with `permitAll` method and with `authenticated` method for anyRequest, changing this config for `not().authenticated()` and `not().anonymous()` in that order, i get the expected result.